# webdriverio Loop through options in select element

Tags: javascript, loops, selenium, foreach, webdriver-io

Example HTML:

```
<select id="random_text">
    <option value="option1">asadka_TEST</option>
    <option value="option2">Peter Parker</option>
    <option value="option3">Clark Kent</option>
    <option value="option4">aldkfsd_TEST</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code in class

```
class TestPage extends Page {

    get fullNameSelect() {return browser.element('#random_text');}

    iterateAndSelect() {
        this.fullNameSelect.value.ForEach() //pseudo code
    }
}
```

I want **iterateAndSelect** function to iterate through all options and select first option that ends with **"_TEST".**

So far, I've only **figured out** that there is `selectByVisibleText` action but the problem is that I want to select option based on condition that value ends with "_TEST" string, and with this action I have to provide the exact value.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java script but in case you want xpath , you can try this `//option[ends-with(text(),'TEST')]`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to find the index of the first option that ends with _TEST:

```
const index = browser.getElements('option').findIndex(option => {
    return option.getText().endsWith('_TEST')
});
```

Then you can select that value by using that index:

```
browser.getElement('select').selectByIndex(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way of doing it.

```js
// get all options
const options = document.getElementById('random_text').children
// filter key test options
const tests = Object.keys(options).filter( i => options[i].text.indexOf('_TEST') > 0)
// run tests here
tests.map(i => {
  console.log(options[i].text)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="random_text">
    <option value="option1">asadka_TEST</option>
    <option value="option2">Peter Parker</option>
    <option value="option3">Clark Kent</option>
    <option value="option4">aldkfsd_TEST</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is Webdriverio code you want to give a try:

```
class TestPage extends Page {

  get fullNameSelect() {return browser.elements("option");}

  iterateAndSelect() {
       var arr=[];

     this.fullNameSelect.value.forEach(function(elem) {

     var text=browser.elementIdText(elem.ELEMENT).value;
     if(text.endsWith('_TEST')) {
        arr.push(text); 
     }
     console.log(arr); // all texts that ends with _TEST
    });
 }
   }
module.exports = new TestPage();
```