# How to get the index of the element pointed to by the selector in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, html, testing, css-selectors, webdriver-io

I write tests using **WebdriverIO** with Chrome.
I'm trying to specify a selector containing a specific text and get the index of the matching element.

HTML:

```
...
<div class="parent">
    <span>lorem</span>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <span>dolor</span>
    <span>sit</span>
    <span>amet</span>
</div>
...
```

---

Test:

```
let result = browser.ANYTHING_WDIO_API('.parent span*=dolor');
// -> `result` expected: 3 or [3]
```

How to do it?

Comment: Do you mean its index relative to the parent? As in :nth-child()? Zero-based or one-based?

Comment: I wanted an index for the nearest parent.

> Zero-based or one-based
Either's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a solution similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451671/150552).

Something like:

```
const elements = $$('.parent span')

const index = elements.findIndex(function (el) {
    return el.getText() === 'dolor';
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://try.webdriver.io/share/WbGshv6ODLnbDQN3).